# Using dot notation for keys when retrieving subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I use this scheme to store some documents:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "param0": "value0",
  "status": {
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": "value3"
  }
}
```

.. and when I request for certain fields inside subdocument

```
db.collection.find({}, {"param0": 1, "status.param1": 1, "status.param3": 1})
```

.. it returns nested object as it's actually used:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "param0": "value0",
  "status": {
    "param1": "value1",
    "param3": "value3"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve it like this?

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "param0": "value0",
  "status.param1": "value1",
  "status.param3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: Nope; you'd have to reshape the returned doc in your own code to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very close to what you want if you use the aggregation framework to transform your document:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project:{
        param0: 1,
        status_param1: "$status.param1",
        status_param3: "$status.param3"
    }
})
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5207908547bbc806a99c5198"),
        "param0" : "value1",
        "status_param1" : "value1",
        "status_param3" : "value3"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

You should, hopefully, be able to work with this type of result.

More information about mongodb [project aggregator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, have a look at [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#subdocuments).

The example took from there reflects your need:

```
db.inventory.find({
  producer: {
    company: 'ABC123',
    address: '123 Street'
  }
})

db.inventory.find({'producer.company': 'ABC123'})
```

Comment: Oh, no. I specify sub fields using dot notation and I want to get each sub field using also dot notation like in the last code block I wrote.